# CSS Grid a gap between 2 rows without gap or padding etc

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid layout with two rows, my problem is that there's a gap between the first and secondrow and there's no padding, gap, margin.

I thought the problem is the a tag which wraps the img but if I remove them it doesn't change anything.

When I use the inspector to inspect the gap there's only the wrapped  `<a>` wrapped arround the img but even I remove this there's this gap.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

}

body{
  height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   margin:0;

}

.count{
  font-size: 40px;

}
.loaded{
  font-size: 40px;

}

.links{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  min-height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}
.container-loading{
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width:400px;
  background-color: grey;
  border:1px solid black;
  display: grid;

  grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr) );
}

.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr) );
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 40px;
  grid-template-areas:
  "userimg"
  "username";
}

.user-name{
  grid-area: username;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;
  color:white;

}

.user-img{
  grid-area: userimg;
}

.usrimg {

}
```

```html
 
<div class="container-loading">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="user-name">
      Username
    </div>
    <div class="user-image">
      <a href="https://www..com/#/profile">
        <img class="usrimg" src="https://www.core-studio.de/212img.png">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @Michael_B I've added to the html an image link. I can reproduce it in jsfiddle

Comment: `vertical-align:top` to the image will fix the issue